# Context Free Grammars to Prolog?

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

From your knowledge of translation and Type 2 grammars, recall example , defined 
as follows:

```
G = {N, T, S, P} 
T = {x, y, z} 
N = {A, B, C} 
S = A 
P = 
< A> ::= x<B>
< A> ::= x<C> 
< B> ::= x<B> 
< B> ::= y 
< C> ::= x<C> 
< C> ::= z
```

Write Prolog rules to represent this grammar. Test with the following lists:

```
[x,x,x,z]. 
[x, x, y]. 
[x]. 
[x, y, z]. 
[ ]
```

Can someone help me with this question? I have no idea on how to represent this in prolog as most examples on the net are very different!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just an hint, complete your assignment adding a clause for each production

```
'A' --> [x], 'B'.
...
```

test it this way

```
?- phrase('S', [x,x,x,z], []).
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `phrase/3` here... in place of `phrase/2`